# Microsoft one note graph api doesn't load pages in a section

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I'm unable to load the pages in a particular section using MS graph API.

URL:  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/0-E6AC34B29128DCBF!181/pages?top=100
Status Code: 504 Gateway Timeout

{
"error": {
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-06-30T07:32:29",
"request-id": "78ca8283-4e8c-4497-ab9e-a0b32985b507"
}
}
}

Comment: Interestingly, I've noticed occasionally a section will not play nicely with the onenote API. I get an unknown 500 error. I inadvertently used one such section as a template for multiple notebooks resulting in the same behaviour being replicated everywhere. if MS are interested I can provide a copy of the .one file in question